# SQL query to add a column value as a separate row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query like -

```
SELECT
    person_number,
    pay_num,
    reg_hours,
    Hour3,
    hour4,
    Work_sched
FROM 
    (
       -- a SUB QUERY
    )
```

This is returning data like this:

```
person_number       pay_num         reg_hours       Hour3  hour3_code       hour4   hour4_code      Work_sched
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                   109             10               09     SCK              4          UNP         Shift_a
1                   109                              8      JUR                                     Shift_a

2                   209             8               10      PTD             10         SOL          Shift_b
2                   209                             6.5     REGR                                    Shift_b
```

I want the reg_hours to be NULL for all cases, and the hour3 column should be added with one more row with the reg_hours value and code 'STR'.

Something like :

```
person_number       pay_num         reg_hours       Hour3  hour3_code       hour4   hour4_code      Work_sched
1                   109                              09     SCK              4          UNP         Shift_a
1                   109                              8      JUR                                     Shift_a
1                   109                              10     STR                                     Shift_a

2                   209                             10      PTD             10         SOL          Shift_b
2                   209                             6.5     REGR                                    Shift_b
2                   209                             8       STR                                     Shift_b
```

I wrote this query for it:

```
SELECT 
    person_number,
    pay_num,
    NULL reg_hours,
    CASE 
        WHEN reg_hours IS NOT NULL 
            THEN 'STR'
            ELSE  HOUR3_CODE
    END AS HOUR3_CODE
    CASE 
        WHEN reg_hours IS NOT NULL 
            THEN reg_hours
            ELSE Hour3
    END AS Hour3,
    hour4,
    Work_sched
FROM 
    (
        -- a SUB QUERY
    )
```

This is not returning the desired output, and is in fact replacing the existing hour3 and hour3_code instead of adding a line of reg_hours.

How to tweak this ?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to implement this with a union query:

- first half to produce the original rows (but reg_hours set to NULL)
- second half to add the new rows with the STR code

This may result in a duplicate SUB QUERY, which can be avoided using the WITH statement (like shown [here](https://www.oraclerecipes.com/sql/using-with-to-avoid-duplicate-code)),

Comment: is there any other way ? Sub query is pretty big and hence was thinking to try another option

Comment: @Sree: what's your issue with using "WITH"? There are  two standard ways to produce more output rows from a query than input rows: using a join ("multiplicative"), and using a union ("additive").  In this case. I think a UNION would be the natural choice.